# Do I need to install headers for my kernel in Debian 9?

Tags: debian, kernel

"Don't Call Me Lenny!" [recommends](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eUnfVG7Zst0&t=9m29s) users to install the appropriate headers in Debian 9 via `apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,')`. It is also recommended for installing Nvidia Graphics drivers in the wiki [here](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers).

Would this be useful to a Debian 9.1 with KDE system without Nvidia graphics card? And why isn't this done automatically? I thought it wasn't required and the CPU works as it should without any further configuration.

Comment: Some driver packages utilize the kernel headers package.  If properly maintained, the driver package should mark them as a dependency and your package manager would install them automagically for you.  Some are not so maintained.

Answer (score 1):

Well maybe this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47330/what-exactly-are-linux-kernel-headers) can help you to understand why and when to use linux headers.

In you practical question, if you don't need any package that explicitly requires linux headers, you don't need to install them.

Hope it helps to see clearer the meaning and use from linux headers.