# what's difference between src version 3.* and 3.*-generic

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel

In my local Linux/Ubuntu, I have two directories for Linux src

```
/usr/src/linux-3.16.0
/usr/src/linux-3.16.0-generic
```

I found the code in 3.16.0 is much more than that in 3.16.0-generic. I am wondering why and how those two directories are different (and what do they represent?)

Answer (score 1):

The two directories are provided by the corresponding packages, which contain the header files for the kernel. Use `dpkg` command to find which package provide the directories.

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/src/linux*
linux-headers-X.XX.X-XX: /usr/src/linux-headers-X.XX.X-XX
linux-headers-X.XX.X-XX-generic: /usr/src/linux-headers-X.XX.X-XX-generic
...
```

The first directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-X.X.XX-XX` comprises header files for multiple architectures, including x86, amd64, powerpc and others, resulting in more number of files and larger size of package.

The other directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-X.X.XX-XX-generic` seemed to contain mostly source codes relevant to x86 architecture that is targeted for the local installation.

The corresponding package has hinted in the description, for example:

```
$ apt-cache show linux-headers-3.16.0-25 | grep -A3 Description-en
Description-en: Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.16.0
 This package provides kernel header files for version 3.16.0, for sites
 that want the latest kernel headers. Please read
 /usr/share/doc/linux-lts-utopic-headers-3.16.0-25/debian.README.gz for details
```

As far as I am aware, both directories contain only source codes and not binaries. And the difference between both is mainly the *target architecture* of source codes.

Related: [What does a kernel source tree contain? Is this related to Linux kernel headers?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/27042/125388)

### Extended answer (2015.07.30)

> since both store `x86` related code, what is the difference btwn the `x86` code in the two directories? – Richard Jul 29 '15 at 19:11

Most of directories and files contained in `/usr/src/linux-headers-X.X.XX-XX-generic` are symbolic links, which pointing to actual directories and files in `/usr/src/linux-headers-X.X.XX-XX`. In other words, `arch/x86` found in those two directories are just the difference of actual and symbolic links, with some leftover files of `asm` headers in `*-generic` counterpart.

Between those two packages, one may notice another major difference is the presence of `config` and `generated` directories in `*-generic` counterpart.

At my best understanding, I would think that `*-generic` directory holds the necessary header files for configuring and compiling modules relevant to `x86` architecture, *without* making accidential changes to the source directory of `linux-headers-x.x.xx-xx`.

Above all, the two directories are probably the "clean" approach to packaging and compiling the packages on respective platforms. Although, I am not in position to clarify this matter.

---

**Answerer's note**: I wrote this answer naively at the time--not sure what is correct or wrong--and some explanation may be missing in between. Hence this answer is now a community wiki, so that anyone with minimum reputation can improve this post to fully explain the difference.

Comment: since both store `x86` related code, what is the difference btwn the `x86` code in the two directories?

Comment: @Richard I have updated my answer as above at my best of knowledge, as simple as possible. My answer may be seen as naive, so you may want to look for better answer from someone else instead.