# What is a kernel-source-tree?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, source

What is the Linux kernel source tree?
What does it contain and what is its purpose?

I'm trying to build an external module and the tutorial I'm using says to make sure that a kernel source tree is available.

If it is available, where can I find it in Ubuntu?

There is a similar question here:

[What does a kernel source tree contain? Is this related to Linux kernel headers?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27042/what-does-a-kernel-source-tree-contain-is-this-related-to-linux-kernel-headers)

but I don't see the answer to my questions.

It would be nice to have this clarified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The source-tree is a directory which contains all of the kernel source.  You could build a new kernel, install that, and reboot your machine to use the rebuilt kernel.  Other than for learning, people rebuild the kernel to select less-used options, or to add device drivers which are normally not bundled with Linux.

You may not find it *in* Ubuntu, but would have to download the source tar-file, e.g., from `kernel.org`.  Ubuntu uses Debian packages for many things, and the latter's website makes it easier to find the packages.

- http://packages.ubuntu.com/
- https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages

Those consist (in either case) of a "pristine" tar-file (from "upstream") and a "debian" add-on (scripts and packages).  You can download both of those from Debian.  If you are looking for the source for the kernel package which you have installed, you would download both parts.

You can also install the "linux-source" package: Debian and [Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-source&searchon=names&suite=wily&section=all) provide a few source-packages, this is one of the few (a quick check finds only a couple of dozen packages with "-source" in their names, compared to tens of thousands of other packages).  The source-package is preferred, since there are many fixes (and customizations) needed, and the source-package has those patches incorporated into the tree.

I used to routinely build kernels until about ten years ago, since the drivers for sound, video and network were lacking.

Comment: So the source-tree contains all the source code for some kernel-version? And I could use it to recompile the kernel?

Answer (score 0):

Kernel developers often talk about "My tree" and "That tree" referring to particular git repositories. The directory tree structure looks different depending on which branch or tag is currently checked out in a git repository. The system of branches in a git can *also* be thought of as a tree structure (hence the name "branch"), which is a totally different concept than the directory structure. Therefore the answer to the first question is not as straightforward as it may seem. In my experience, for some people the term "Kernel tree" means the set of git branches and their content that is present in a particular git repository of kernel sources. They would say that "linux-next" is a different tree than the mainline tree.